# Find specific extension from directory

Tags: powershell

I have a root directory which contains several child directories and inside one of them I have my `.ps1` file that I want to get:

```
function GetFileNames
{
    $folders = Get-ChildItem "c:\myFolder"
    $filename = [System.IO.Directory]$folders[0].GetFiles($folders[0].FullName, "*.ps1", "AllDirectories")
}
```

So inside this path: `c:\myFolder` I have several folders and all I want to do is to take the first folder and inside this folder find my `.ps1 file`.
Currently this `$filename` value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can *select the first item* and call the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet again:

```
function GetFileNames
{
    Get-ChildItem "c:\myFolder" -Directory | 
        select -first 1 | 
        Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.ps1' -recurse | 
        select -expand Name
}
```

But this looks a little bit awkward to me. What do you wan't to achieve?